# React Frontend Routing Issue with Flask Backend

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-router

I'm working on a project with a Flask backend and a React frontend, but I'm encountering a routing problem.

Only the main route (`"/"`) seems to be working as expected. When I try to access another route, like `"/sign-in"`, I don't receive an error, but I get redirected back to the main page (`"/"`). Even routes that do not exist seem to redirect me to the main page instead of returning a 404 error.

This is my backend:

```py
# Serve static files
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/<path:path>")
def serve_static(path=""):
    return app.send_static_file("index.html")

@app.route("/favicon.ico")
def favicon():
    return app.send_static_file('favicon.ico')

@app.route("/assets/<path:path>")
def assets(path):
    return send_from_directory("static/assets", path)
```

My react router:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Chat />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/sign-in">
          <Route index element={<SignInStart />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

Comment: You are using a `HashRouter`, so all the requests to the server *should* just be `"/"` or whatever directory you are hosting/serving the app from. I'm unfamiliar with Flask though so I've no idea if your configuration there is problematic, but the router code seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things first:

1. Make sure you are using the proper hash urls. In your case you have used `HashRouter`. It is different from `BrowserRouter`.
2. Make sure you are using `Outlet` in your Layout page.

Working example:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import { HashRouter, Route, Routes, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => (
  <>
    <p>Layout</p>
    <hr />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
const Chat = () => <p>Chat</p>;
const NoPage = () => <p>NoPage</p>;
const SignInStart = () => <p> SignInStart</p>;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <HashRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route index element={<Chat />} />
          <Route path="*" element={<NoPage />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="/sign-in">
          <Route index element={<SignInStart />} />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </HashRouter>
  );
}
```

- Url: `https://example.com/#/sign-in` will render sign in page
- Url: `https://example.com/` will render Chat page
- Url: `https://example.com/#/nonexistentroute` will render No Page.

If you don't require hashed urls, consider moving to [BrowserRouter](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router) instead which can understand normal URLs.